# After compile application fails to find main class

Tags: java, package, javac

I made a really simple java example with two files:

Dog.java contains:

```
package com.greg.dog;

public class Dog {
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("bark");
    }
}
```

TestDog.java contains:

```
package com.greg.dog;

public class TestDog {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
        Dog d = new Dog();
        d.bark();
    }
}
```

I have these two files in the location ~/Desktop/test/src/com/greg/dog

When I compile them, Dog.java compiles fine, but TestDog.java can't find my Dog class:

```
user1@blackpearl:~/Desktop/test/src/com/greg/dog$ javac Dog.java 
user1@blackpearl:~/Desktop/test/src/com/greg/dog$ javac TestDog.java 
TestDog.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Dog
location: class com.greg.dog.TestDog
        Dog d = new Dog();
        ^
TestDog.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Dog
location: class com.greg.dog.TestDog
        Dog d = new Dog();
                    ^
2 errors
```

I'm on Ubuntu, here's all the java information:

```
java version "1.6.0_0"
IcedTea6 1.3.1 (6b12-0ubuntu6.7) Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_0-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.6.0_0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?  Do I need to import Dog.java?  Am I doing packages wrong?

**Update**

Per Anon's suggestion, I changed directories to the src directory and everything compiles.  However when I go to run TestDog.java I get this error:

```
user1@blackpearl:~/Desktop/test/src$ java com/greg/dog/TestDog.java 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/greg/dog/TestDog/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.greg.dog.TestDog.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:264)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:332)
Could not find the main class: com/greg/dog/TestDog.java. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Java compiler expects other classes to be in the package-appropriate directory *relative to where the compiler is invoked from*.

You'll want to be compiling using something like:

```
user1@blackpearl:~/Desktop/test/src$ javac com/greg/dog/Dog.java
user1@blackpearl:~/Desktop/test/src$ javac com/greg/dog/TestDog.java
```

Comment: Thanks.  Compiling both worked from that directory, but when I go to run it I get a class not found error.  See update.

Comment: @Greg: You don't want to have the `.java` extension when launching - try `java com/greg/dog/TestDog`.

Comment: @Anon: Actually, the preferred form would be `java com.greg.dog.TestDog`.